# Recovering data and fixing RAW format on Seagate Backup Plus 4TB External Hard Drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, format

I need some help from you.

I'm on Windows 10 with a 4TB Seagate Backup Plus External Hard Drive and it seems to be in RAW format. I say "it seems" because it is really hard to try to load/access to metadata and data allocated in it.

**These is what I've done until now:**

**1.** Windows file explorer gets stuck trying to load it ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YKBO.png)). Also, despite Windows gives it a device letter, it never shows the blue/red bar representing the size of the allocated and stored data.

**2.** Disk Management also gets stuck trying to load it ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szVHI.png)).

**3.** CMD command chkdsk e: /f /r /x also gets stuck trying to work ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szVHI.png)). I have to say when I stopped one of my attempts to run this command it said the hdd is RAW formatted (and anything else), but this output appeared just once. Every other attempt to run this command I had to stop it because it takes too long.

I don't know if these 3 points take too much time because the hdd is 4TB or the hdd has other errors. But I have to say it takes reaaally long while trying to do any of those 3 points.

**These is what I would like you to help me:**

**1.** Trying to fix the hdd without losing its data. (or recovering its data or part of it before fixing /format it) [A plus here: I have to say right click on the device in file explorer don't work either; it makes the mouse icon a loading icon and windows not responding]

**2.** Fixing the hdd regardless of lost its data.

Of course I would prefer solution 1 but if it doesn't exist, then solution 2 will be really appreciated as well.

I would really appreciate your help.

PD: when windows/disk management/chkdsk keeps loading/working and I unplug the hdd, the problem is solved and windows/disk management/chkdsk works again.

Comment: What does the BIOS say about this disk?

Comment: @harrymc What do you mean? I have done nothing at BIOS level.

Comment: I would like to know if the BIOS detects this disk and what does it say about it.

Comment: @harrymc BIOS says nothing: pc just starts as usual and doesn't check for any error on disk.

Comment: Boot into the BIOS to see. Press a key during boot, perhaps F12 or F2 or Esc, according to your  computer.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry I still don't get what you mean, but nothing happens when I get into the BIOS. It first asked me if I wanted to start running Windows or enter the BIOS (as usually when I press F2) and then in BIOS there is nothing different, also nothing for boot from (other than Windows I say)

Comment: @Jose: Hairymc wants to know if your BIOS recognizes your external hard disk!

Comment: @r2d3 I guess it doesn't because I don't see anything different or anything related to my hdd. Also, I have to say my hdd light is on and the inside of the hdd (its hardware) is working because I feel it when i place my hand on it.

Comment: If your external harddrive is connected by a USB plug that is leading directly to the mainboard (no extension card used) your BIOS should list your drive, p.e. in the menu where you set the boot order.